# PHP PDO MySQL query prints blank

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Going through a PHP MySQL tutorial and switching the PHP out for PDO; at any rate, my query is coming up blank.

```
$get_cat = $that->dbh->query("SELECT `cat_name`, `cat_desc` FROM `categories`");

            if(isset($get_cat))
            {
        while($row = $get_cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                printf("
                <tr>
                    <td>".$row['cat_name']." : ".$row['cat_desc']."</td>
                </tr>
                ");
            }
            }
            else
                {
                    echo '<tr><td>return is false</td></tr>';
                }
```

$That refers to:

```
include('db.php');
$that = new lib();
```

OLD:
So, why is my query blank? Before putting the die in it would return Boolean and give in an error in the loop with the die in it just comes up blank. The categories table has data in it and the page is refreshed on submission for new entries.
NEW:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\forum\create_category.php on line 36

Line 36 is the while loop line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell PDO to throw errors.

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$res = $that->dbh->query("SELECT cat_name, cat_desc FROM categories");
while($row = $res->fetch())
{
    echo "<tr><td>$row[cat_name] : $row[cat_desc]</td></tr>\n";
}
```

run your code, read the error message and take appropriate action

Don't forget to add the first line into your db.php file, to make the setting permanent

Comment: This printed the error and it was resolved; as simple as I forgot I didn't use cat_desc on this table but cat_description. @jeroen This was the solution. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @jeroen I responded to your post giving the PDO connection; it was `function con($host,$db,$user,$pass) { $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db","$user","$pass"); }` it was given 17-18min ago from time of this post.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_fetch_array` is not PDO. You would need something like:

```
while($row = $get_cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

To get your rows.

Nor can you use `mysql_error()` to get the error. You could use for example `$that->dbh->errorInfo()` but you should look into exceptions for a more robust way to catch all errors.

**Edit:** You should check what the error is. Using `isset` is pointless as you have just assigned a value to it, so it will always be set.

Comment: jeroen and @sgeddes thanks! I made changes to the query and switched from the PHP while to the PDO while. The error now received is Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\forum\create_category.php on line 36. line 36 is the while loop. Updating post with new code to include error.

Comment: @Louis Milotte Check what the error is using `errorInfo()`. And post your connection script, perhaps there are remains of `mysql_*` functions as well.

Comment: I tried using errorInfo() as `print_r($that->dbh->errorInfo());` but i'm getting not getting anything from it. Connection script is `function con($host,$db,$user,$pass)
    {
     $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db","$user","$pass");
    }`

Comment: @Louis Milotte Without seeing your include it is impossible to tell what is wrong.

Comment: include is `include('db.php');` db.php houses the class containing the connection function; however, the query for categories is on the same page as the insert to categories; the insert works.. the select does not.

Comment: @Louis Milotte You mixed up `mysql_*` and PDO and like I said, without seeing the include it is impossible to tell what's wrong. But good error handling (using exceptions in PDO) helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect -- is this what you're trying to do?

```
SELECT `categories`.`cat_name`, `categories`.`cat_desc` FROM `categories`
```

Hard to know without seeing you table structure.